# UIWebView and history statePush()

Tags: html, uiwebview, pushstate

I am working on a small app, that has to detect changes in the url of an UIWebView.
However when I tap a link in the UIWebView, the html5 changes the history and the url of the page via statePush() (e.g. mixcloud.com), but I can't detect the change with the `webView(webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: navigationType:` method, it detects only the external requests.

How can I detect the URL changes?

Answer (score 0):

delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad` does the trick! Sorry for bothering you, guys :)